# Verify hashed passwords using PHP from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to develop a login form using HTML, PHP, and SQL. I'm scratching my head on trying to figure out what my issue is and how to fix it as I'm relatively new to PHP, so I'd appreciate some help. What I want to do is to check if the user's input on the HTML login form (in this case the password) matches the hashed password that is stored inside the database.

However, I'm currently having an issue where it doesn't do that. The code should verify the password and if it is correct, it should echo *"password and username match"* else it should echo *"incorrect password"* however the code does not echo anything.

Here is what I've tried:

[get password using username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496668/mysql-php-get-column-using-another-column-get-password-using-username)

I am using PHP's **password_hash** plugin to hash and verify the user's password.

So my question is, how do I securely verify the user's input (the password) with the hashed password that is stored inside the database?

**Here is the PHP code:**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //declare variables and set values to null
    $username = $pass = "";
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    //check if username exists
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userName FROM userDetails WHERE userName=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $prepname);
    $prepname = $username;
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //if username exists, check if password is linked to user
        echo "user exists";
        $stmt = "SELECT userPass FROM userDetails WHERE userName=?";
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $prepname);
        $prepname = $username;
        $hashpass = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($hashpass);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if (password_verify($pass, $hashpass)) {
            echo "password and username match";
        }
        else {
            echo "incorrect password";
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "That user does not exist!";
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Jovi, I have fixed the previous error however I am now recieving a new error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'userPass' in /home/toeaimc2/public_html/php/pages/login.php on line 75
```

**EDIT:**
@Jovi has now solved the problem! Thank you to everyone for their help!

Comment: Have you checked if you're at least getting the complete hashed password from the database? The password column being too short is a common problem

Comment: did you debug this? What is the content of $hashpass? Probably an associative array like this: $hashpass["userPass"]. If that is true then you would need to write something like "if (password_verify($pass, $hashpass["userPass"])) { ....

Comment: @Joni I've tried echoing the result of the selection with echo $result; however it does not echo anything. I've also tried wrapping $result in quotes. So for example, echo "$result"; and still no output.

Comment: @rf1234 I've applied your suggestion however I still get the same issue :(

Comment: You're calling bind_param on a string, how does this not give you a fatal error? Do not have error reporting enabled? `$stmt = "SELECT userPass FROM userDetails WHERE userName=?";
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $prepname);`

Comment: @rf1234 wont hashing the user input result in a different hash though? Therefore meaning that I can't compare them since they are different?

Comment: @Joni no, I don't have error reporting enabled..... I'm relitively new to PHP so could you show me how to enable it? Thanks.

Comment: sorry, my previous comment was crap! password_verify works using a clear text password and a hashed password from the database. Just checked my own code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: As @Joni politely points out: You have some more or less serious error in your code and you should be able to see this in your browser's console looking at the Network tab in Chrome for example. Otherwise use your debugger. Without a debugger you'll be lost anyway. So I'd rather get that started in the first place ... Good luck.

Comment: @Joni I have enabled error reporting and now I recieve a fatal error. I have edited the question to now show the error that I am recieving. Can you see if you can help? Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Most recently, you run a method on a string(!) which is obviously not working

Comment: @NicoHaase Joni has already helped me fix the error I was previously having. However I am now recieving a new error. Please see the edit to my question. Thanks

Comment: You've attached a new error message, but you should also add your debugging attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `bind_param` method on a string, it should be a statement object.

You are missing the method call to create the prepared statement object for the query that extracts the password:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userPass FROM userDetails WHERE userName=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $prepname);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have applied your suggestion however I am getting a new error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'userPass' in /home/toeaimc2/public_html/php/pages/login.php on line 75. Any idea on what this means? Sorry for the questions. I'm relitively new to PHP :) More specifically, It's on line 75. I'll edit the question to reflect the error.

Comment: Your original code was correct. change `password_verify($pass, $hashpass["userPass"])` back to `password_verify($pass, $hashpass)`